# MSSQL case with raiserror statement error?

Tags: sql-server, case, alwayson, raiserror

I am trying to check if the availability group is running on correct primary replica.

I want to create a job that will fail if primary replica is not specific server.

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN primary_replica != @@SERVERNAME
  THEN  (RAISERROR('Wrong replica', 16, 1))
END 
FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States
```

I expect the query to throw an error if primary replica is not the server that runs the job. However, I'm getting the error below:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'RAISERROR'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Ok. And what is your issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't raise an error in a `case expression` like that. You can use `EXISTS` with `IF` instead. Note, this would run on servers where there wasn't an AG too... so if that isn't intended you'll want to account for that.

```
if exists (SELECT 1 from sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states where  primary_replica != @@SERVERNAME)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Wrong replica', 16, 1)
END
```

For newer versions, you can use [sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-hadr-is-primary-replica-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
If sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica ( db_name() ) <> 1   
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Wrong replica', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: case **EXPRESSION**, not statement. You know that but it always helps to use the correct terminology.

Comment: I’m the worst at that. Thanks @SMor

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in SQL job step to check if Primary replica is not specific server:

```
DECLARE @ServerName NVARCHAR(256)  = @@SERVERNAME 
DECLARE @RoleDesc NVARCHAR(60)

SELECT @RoleDesc = a.role_desc
    FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS a
    JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS b
        ON b.replica_id = a.replica_id
WHERE b.replica_server_name = @ServerName

IF @RoleDesc = 'PRIMARY'
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Error: Wrong replica',16,1 );
END
```